# Get XWPFRun From XWPFParagraph

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want create Word document from another Word document, but I need replace some text in new Word. I do it, but my problem is the new Word Document does not support the old document style. For this I can get XWPFRun from XWPFParagraph. How can I do it?

Note. Eclipse not found paragraph.getRuns() method in my situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On XWPFParagraph is a getRuns() method:

```
public java.util.List<XWPFRun> getRuns()
```

That's the method you need, see the [javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getRuns%28%29) for more info.

Comment: But I have not found getRuns method. I dont understand what is the problem?

Comment: It really is there. Make sure you've got a new enough copy of Apache POI, I'd recommend 3.8 beta 3.

Comment: I am downloaded POI 3.7 Source Code, this function really here, but when I downloaded POI 3.7 Binary there is not such function.

Comment: If it's in the source code then it'll be in the binary too. You've almost certainly got multiple copies of POI, and you're looking at the wrong one.

Comment: thk for attention, I solved my problem. There is no getRuns method in POI 3.6 lib